# Transferring Data from Oracle to SQL Server using recordset

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I need copying table rows from `Oracle database server` to `SQL Server database server` and can't using linked server on SQL server management Studio

I have tried the code below, but I have this error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
> in an out-of-range value.

How can I solve this using SQL query in SQL Server?

```
   SQL = " SELECT "     
   SQL = SQL & " DATE_R, "   
   SQL = SQL & " DATE_I, "    
   SQL = SQL & " DATE_E "   
   SQL = SQL & " FROM "   
   SQL = SQL & " ""XXX"".""tbl_oracle_Server"" "
   
   set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   Rs.Open SQL, cn
   
   If Not Rs.eof then
   Do While Not Rs.EOF 
   
   IF trim(Rs("DATE_R") & "[]") = "[]" then
      dtr = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   Else
      dtr = cDate(Rs("DATE_R"))
   End IF   
   
   IF trim(Rs("DATE_I") & "[]") = "[]" then
      dti = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   Else
      dti = cDate(Rs("DATE_I"))
   End IF   

   IF trim(Rs("DATE_E") & "[]") = "[]" then
      dte = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   Else
      dte = cDate(Rs("DATE_E"))
   End IF   
      
   SQL = " INSERT INTO [XXX].[XXX].[tbl_sql_Server] "   
   SQL = SQL & " ( "     
   SQL = SQL & "  DATE_R, "  
   SQL = SQL & "  DATE_I, "     
   SQL = SQL & "  DATE_E "     
   SQL = SQL & " ) "   
   SQL = SQL & " VALUES " 
   SQL = SQL & " ( "
   SQL = SQL & " CONVERT(datetime, '" & dtr & "', 121), " 
   SQL = SQL & " CONVERT(datetime, '" & dti & "', 121), "
   SQL = SQL & " CONVERT(datetime, '" & dte & "', 121) " 
   SQL = SQL & " ); " 
   ca.execute(SQL) 

   Rs.MoveNext
   Loop  

   End IF
   
   Rs.Close()
   Set Rs = Nothing    
     
   ca.Close()
   Set ca = Nothing 

   cn.Close()
   Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Your alternative 0000-00-00 value will not work since that is not a valid datetime in tsql. So if you don't get a "value" from oracle, what should be the appropriate value to be used in your sql server table? No one but you can answer that. Perhaps NULL? In addition, your connection should determine the database to use - don't code that (as 3 part names) in your generated statements.

Comment: I must add that it is far preferable to use a parameterized statement and avoid all this messy and error-prone string manipulation logic

Comment: @SMor thanks for reply. if don't get a "value" from oracle the value is NULL